# AngularJS won't parse ng-disabled in select

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

All of the following HTML snippets fail with parsing errors *when in a directive template*:

1.

```
<select ng-model="model" ng-options="s.abbreviation as s.name for s in states" ng-disabled="false"></select>
```

fails with:

```
Error: Syntax Error: Token 'false' is an unexpected token at column 18 of the expression [state.isDisabled false] starting at [false]
```

2.

```
<select ng-model="model" ng-options="s.abbreviation as s.name for s in states" ng-disabled="disabled"></select>
```

where `$scope.disabled` is a boolean (`false`) fails with:

```
Error: Syntax Error: Token 'disabled' is an unexpected token at column 18 of the expression [state.isDisabled disabled] starting at [disabled].
```

3.

```
<select ng-model="model" ng-options="s.abbreviation as s.name for s in states" ng-disabled="isDisabled()"></select>
```

where `$scope.isDiabled` is a function fails with:

```
Error: Syntax Error: Token 'isDisabled' is an unexpected token at column 18 of the expression [state.isDisabled isDisabled()] starting at [isDisabled()].
```

When the same code was in the main HTML, it worked fine, but it stopped parsing `ng-disabled` after I moved it to its own directive.

This is the JavaScript used for this directive:

```
myApp.directive("selectState", [
function () {
    var states = [ // src: https://gist.github.com/mshafrir/2646763
    { "name": "Alabama", "abbreviation": "AL" } /*, { .. }, { .. }*/
    ];
    return {
    templateUrl: "/directives/select-state/select-state.html",
    replace: true,
    scope: { model: "=", isDisabled: "=" },
    restrict: "EA",

    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $scope.states = states;
        $scope.disabled = false;
        if (!$scope.isDisabled) {
        $scope.isDisabled = function () { return false };
        }
    }
    }
  }
]);
```

What is wrong with it? If I remove the `ng-disabled` attribute, it works fine.

Comment: can you please provide a plunker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, the including HTML also had `ng-disabled` instead of `is-disabled` so, as it seems (but I may be wrong), AngularJS was concatenating both `ng-disabled` attributes. I didn't spend much time looking into *how* things went wrong, but this was definitely the cause of the error.

I fixed it by changing this:

```
<select-state model="myModel" ng-disabled="myFunc"></select-state>
```

to this:

```
<select-state model="myModel" is-disabled="myFunc"></select-state>
```